# How to open bootstrap modalbox by clicking on the card image in angularjs project

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am writing code for my angularjs project where in one part of UI has cards. So I want to open a modal box by clicking on the card image.
Currently I have created a button below the image and clicking on the button will open the modalbox.
This is working fine. But instead of clicking on the button, I want to click on the card image and it should open the modal box.I am attaching the current code below. Any help regarding this would be highly appreciable. Thank You

```
<div class="col-md-4 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
            <div class="card mb-2">
              <div class="avatar-wrapper">
                <img class="profile-pic" src="/assets/images/abc.jpg" />
                <div class="upload-button">
                 </div>               
              </div>

              <div class="card-body">            

         <h4> <button type="button" class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal3">
            abc receipe </button>  </h4>
                <h3 class="description">This is short description in the card body.hio dvdjvd sscg sdgscsc sgssd sdjg c edsc sdcfsc dfkopseuccs sc</h3 >     
                 <div class= "modal fade" id="basicExampleModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel3"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
               <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel3">Receipe-abc by dfgr</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body ">
                  <img class="profile-pic" src="/assets/images/abc.jpg" />
                 <p> Modal Box Description.                 
                  sdc
                  dfvdv
                  sscg sdgscsc dfvfd
                 </p>
                </div>                
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>                  
                </div>             
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

</div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal3"` to the image element, like this

```
<img class="profile-pic" src="/assets/images/abc.jpg"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal3"/>
```

Check the snippet, now click on the image to open modal

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 clearfix  d-md-block">
  <div class="card mb-2">
    <div class="avatar-wrapper">
      <img class="profile-pic" src="/assets/images/abc.jpg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal3" />
      <div class="upload-button">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">

      <h4> <button type="button" class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">
          abc receipe</button> (click on button wont work, click on image to check) </h4>
      <h3 class="description">This is short description in the card body.hio dvdjvd sscg sdgscsc sgssd sdjg c edsc sdcfsc dfkopseuccs sc</h3>
      <div class="modal fade" id="basicExampleModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel3" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel3">Receipe-abc by dfgr</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body ">
              <img class="profile-pic" src="/assets/images/abc.jpg" />
              <p> Modal Box Description.
                sdc
                dfvdv
                sscg sdgscsc dfvfd
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your time. I added   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal3"    to the image element.But it didn't work.So added this element to the card div.it worked. Thanks for this idea.

Comment: @MIDHUNBOSEK are you sure it didnt work, but the snippet I made worked on image click.